# print vueJS component or convert to pdf

Tags: vue.js, printing, html-to-pdf, html-pdf

I have a vueJS component that I want to print. However, when I use the standard print dialog I lose all the CSS and basically only have plain text.

I have also tried *Printd*.

My code is along the lines of:

```
mounted () {
    this.cssText = `
        .a4-paper {
            height: 29cm;
            width: 14cm;
        }
        h4, h3, h2, h1 {
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
        }
        label.underline {
            border-bottom: solid black 1px;
            height: 0.3cm;
            width: 100%;
        }`;
    this.d = new Printd()  
},
methods: {
    show(event: Event) {
        this.event = event;
        this.visible = true;
    },
    print() {
        this.d.print(this.$el, this.cssText)
    }
}
```

However, the result looks nothing like how the component is rendered. I haven't been able to find a solution for this. Can somebody help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem exists because printd creates a new Document for printing, therefore styles aren't carried down into the child component, which you are referencing with `this.$el`

The workaround which I use is to take all of the style elements from the head of the current document and append them to the document that `printd` creates. Change your print method to the following;

```
print() {
  const d = new Printd()
  d.print(this.$el, this.cssText, (win, doc, node, launchPrint) => {
    // Get style elements
    const styles = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('style'))
    // append them to the the new document head element
    styles.forEach(styleElement => doc.head.appendChild(styleElement.cloneNode(true)))
    launchPrint(win)
  })
},
```